# Is chromatic index of $G$ at most $4$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

> Let $G$ be an outerplanar graph. Is chromatic index of $G$ at most $4$?

I proved that if $G$ is outerplanar then $G$ has chromatic number at most $4$ which can be proved easily using $4$ colour theorem.

However I am stuck here. Is there any relation between chromatic number and chromatic index of a graph?

Also using Vizing's Theorem we know that chromatic index of any graph $G$ is either equal to the maximum degree or maximum degree+1  of a vertex.

Can someone please help me out to prove or disprove this?

Comment: Is $K_{1,8}$ an outerplanar graph? What is its chromatic index?

Comment: @bof; I understand, I can take $K_{1,5}$ also right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between these two numbers for outerplanar graphs.

**Chromatic number**
Using the 4CC to prove that the chromatic number of a simple outerplanar graph is at most $4$ is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Furthermore the chromatic number can be proved to be at most $3$.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph#:~:text=According%20to%20Vizing's%20theorem%2C%20the,one%20plus%20the%20maximum%20degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph#:%7E:text=According%20to%20Vizing%27s%20theorem%2C%20the,one%20plus%20the%20maximum%20degree).

**Chromatic index**

In the comments it is pointed out that there is no bound on this number for simple outerplanar graphs.